# Use bump in Phonegap (Cordova)

Tags: ios, cordova, bump

Is there any way to integrate the Bump SDK into PhoneGap (Cordova) for iOS/Android? If anyone has any suggestions on where to start I would appreciate it. I'm thinking I may have download the bump SDK and create a plugin to somehow Interface with the JS Script? Has anyone done similar previously?

Cheers,
Matt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will need to write a plugin in order to integrate Bump.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide

Comment: Thanks Simon. If anyone is interested I've got a basic version of a bump Cordova plugin working. Still needs some work but once done I will upload to GitHub if anyone wants it.

Comment: Yeah, you should push it to github.

Comment: Did you ever put this on github? I am interested in the same usage. Thanks!